# Adaptive server connection failed (DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9)

Tags: python, azure-sql-database, pymssql

I'm sure this issue has been raised an uncountable number of times before but perhaps, someone could still help me.
I am using pymssql v2.1.3 with Python 2.7.12 and the code that I used several times until yesterday to write data to my Azure SQL DB has somehow decided not to work anymore - for no apparent reason.

The firewall is set, my IP is in the whitelist, I can connect to the database using SQL Server Management Studio and query the data but I still keep getting this error when attempting to connect using pymssql.

The app is a Flask web-app and following is how I connect to the DB:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server='myserver.database.windows.net', user='myusername@mydatabase', password='mypassword', database='mydatabase')
```

Comment: I would recommend using pymssql==2.1.1. There was a change in the later versions that prevents auto SSL handshakes. Alternatively, I would recommend using pyodbc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-develop-python-simple

Answer (score 5):

This is likely due to the pymssql version. Did you upgrade pymssql? If yes, try reverting back to 2.1.1

```
sudo pip install pymssql==2.1.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Not really a solution to the issue I raised, but using pypyodbc instead of pymssql works.

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}',server='tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433',database='mydatabase', uid='myusername', pwd='mypassword')
```

Answer (score 3):

Here can work on my workspace
pymssql version: 2.2.8
python verison: 3.11

```
conn = pymssql.connect(host=r'10.0.1.29:60001\sql2019', user='sa', password='sa', charset='UTF-8', atabase=r'database1', tds_version=r'7.0')
```

the tds_version should be set 7.0 if you used pymssql 2.2.8. you can have a try other tds_version(7.4,7.3,7.2,7.1,7.0...) if you still encountered issue

you can add addtional version informaiton and debug code

```
print('pymssql version: ', pymssql.__version__)
print('get_dbversion: ', pymssql.get_dbversion())
print('version_info: ', pymssql.version_info())
os.environ['TDSDUMP'] = 'stdout'
```

Answer (score 1):

freetds-dev might be missing on linux:

`apt-get update && apt-get install freetds-dev`

Answer (score 0):

unbelievable the bug is still present...
ENV: WSL2 on Windows 10

Fix -> switch to pyodbc:.

1. sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev && pip3 install pyodbc
2. follow instruction for ubuntu
   https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15
3. 

```
    import pyodbc 
server = 'tcp:myserver.database.windows.net' 
database = 'mydb' 
username = 'myusername' 
password = 'mypassword' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Answer (score 0):

conn = pymssql.connect(server='ip',user='sa',password='pwd',database='db',as_dict=True,tds_version='7.0')

1. tds_version = 7.0 ~7.3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).