# How do I access my Azure SQL database (not in a container) from within a docker container

Tags: sql-server, azure, pymssql

I have a SQL Server running on docker. I'm trying to connect to it from a web app written in python3 with pymssql.

It's working until I run the same app inside a docker container.

I get this error:

> 20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (nameofmydb.database.windows.net:1433)\n'.

Code:

```
pymssql.connect(server='mydb.database.windows.net', port='1433', database='mydb', user='user@server', password='pwd')
```

I tried with `--net=host` but it doesn't work either.

Can someone help me, please?

EDIT: So i finally succeeded after around 2 days , it was because of the installation of odbc driver in the container i was doing it in a wrong way.
Also i was forced to use pyodbc yes.
Install the odbc drivers + python the way azure tell you to in the docs and use pyodbc and not pymssql (which works outside of docker).

Comment: Can you try pinging/curling from your container to see if you can get anywhere on the internet?

Comment: It works I have access to Internet

Comment: I wonder if port 1433 is blocked (?)

Answer (score 0):

You can reference this blog: [Adaptive server connection failed (DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991190/adaptive-server-connection-failed-db-lib-error-message-20002-severity-9).

Try to use `pyodbc` instead of `pymssql`. I tried and it works well.

```
import pyodbc
server = 'XXX.database.windows.net'
database = 'dbname'
username = 'username'
password = 'psd'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
```

The Azure document [Quickstart: Use Python to query an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-python) also provides the example:

```
import pyodbc
server = '<server>.database.windows.net'
database = '<database>'
username = '<username>'
password = '<password>'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 20 pc.Name as CategoryName, p.name as ProductName FROM [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] pc JOIN [SalesLT].[Product] p ON pc.productcategoryid = p.productcategoryid")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So i did all of these .

But now i have this :

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

i used the odbcinst.ini that is in connection strngs in the azure pannel which correspond to :

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so 
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount=1
```

I changed driver and setup to suit the docker container.
The pyodbc code is :

`pyodbc.connect(
                    'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:mydb.database.windows.net,1433;Database=mydb;Uid=myuser@mydb;Pwd=mypwd;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;'))`

Also i repeat it but it looks that everything works well outside the docker container . i have absolutely no clue what is going on ...

Comment: The Uid = username, not username@server.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the problem, seems to me that it was connection string which was causing the issue.

```
import pyodbc
server = 'xxxx.database.windows.net'
database = 'xxxx'   
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
username='xxxxx@xxx.com'
password = 'xxxxxx'



with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password+';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT top 4 * FROM [dbo].[TableName]")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row:
            print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
            row = cursor.fetchone()
```